# DB results to hierarchy - flexible size

Tags: php

I have the following following data coming from the db (I don't control this) - it could just have a_id and a_title or it could have a_id/a_title to z_id/z_title

If could be:

```
|a_id| a_title |b_id| b_title |c_id| c_title |
|   1|A Title 1|   1|B Title 1|   1|C Title 1|
|   1|A Title 1|   1|B Title 1|   2|C Title 2|
|   1|A Title 1|   2|B Title 2|   3|C Title 3|
|   1|A Title 1|   2|B Title 2|   4|C Title 4|
|   2|A Title 2|   3|B Title 3|   5|C Title 5|
|   2|A Title 2|   3|B Title 3|   6|C Title 6|
|   2|A Title 2|   4|B Title 4|   7|C Title 7|
|   2|A Title 2|   4|B Title 4|   8|C Title 8|
```

or

```
|a_id| a_title |b_id| b_title |
|   1|A Title 1|   1|B Title 1|
|   1|A Title 1|   2|B Title 2|
|   2|A Title 2|   3|B Title 3|
|   2|A Title 2|   4|B Title 4|
```

What I would like to end up with is something like

```
$data = [

    '1' => [

        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'A Title 1',
        'children' => [
            '1' => [
                'id' => 1,
                'title' => 'B Title 1',
                'children' => [
                    '1' => [
                        'id' => 1,
                        'title' => 'C Title 1',
                    ],
                    '2' => [
                        'id' => 2,
                        'title' => 'C Title 2',
                    ],
                ]
            ],
            '2' => [
                'id' => 1,
                'title' => 'B Title 2',
                'children' => [
                    '3' => [
                        'id' => 3,
                        'title' => 'C Title 3',
                    ],
                    '4' => [
                        'id' => 4,
                        'title' => 'C Title 4',
                    ],
                ]
            ],
        ],

    ],

];
```

I do know what fields I am expecting, for example I have the following array:

```
$fields = [
    'a',
    'b',
    'c',
];
```

I would usually post some code, but I'm kind of stuck with where to start on this, and am wondering if I'm taking the wrong approach, though as I don't have control over the DB I'm kind of out of ideas

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using a different approach - it requires a query per hierarchy, but the queries aren't too heavy and makes the code much simpler